# Getting "None" and 'NoneType object...' error when using BeautifulSoup4 to get Text from a webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, html, python-2.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull the main headline (currently: "Wenger predicts 'active' January") from BBC Sport page. The ID is 'lead-caption' and it's in a `<h2>` and an `<a>` tag. I'm using Python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/arsenal")
soup=BeautifulSoup(url.read())
#Things I've tried
headline=soup.find('a', attrs={'id': 'lead-caption'})
print headline
#The above prints 'None'
headline1=soup.find('lead-caption').getText()
print headline1
#The above print "'NoneTpye' Object has no attirbute 'getText'
tag = soup.a
tag ['id'] = 'lead-caption'
type(tag)
print tag.string
#Error: NoneType object does not support item assignment
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you are seeking in wrong element that's why you are getting `None`, it should be `div`:

```
headline=soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'lead-caption'})
headline_text=headline.find('a').getText()
print headline_text
```

Output:

> Wenger predicts 'active' January

Comment: Use `str.strip()` on the `print` statement to get rid of the whitespace around the text :)